# Stream multiple Properties - Java 8 (Basic Example)

Tags: java, methods, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Java 8 and I can get the `max` and `min`. Works great but I need to check also the `max` and `min` of 10 more properties (*e.g.,* `User` **age, prop1, prop2, prop3, etc...)**.

How can I do it this instead of replicate the same code 10 times?

```
IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = data.stream()
            .mapToInt(User::getProp2)
            .summaryStatistics();
    
    int max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
    int min = summaryStatistics.getMin();
```

And normalize the data between 0 and 5

```
 data.stream().forEach(d -> {
        d.setNormalized(5 * ((d.getProp2() - min) / (max - min));)
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the good old method refactoring in combination with the [ToIntFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) interface

```
public static void normalization(Collection<User> data, ToIntFunction<User> getProp) {
    IntSummaryStatistics summaryStatistics = data.stream()
            .mapToInt(getProp)
            .summaryStatistics();

    int max = summaryStatistics.getMax();
    int min = summaryStatistics.getMin();

    data.forEach(d -> d.setNormalized(5 * ((getProp.applyAsInt(d) - min) / (max - min))));
}
```

The parameter `ToIntFunction<User> getProp` is for the "age, prop1, prop2, prop3" part.

To call the method:

```
normalization(data, User::getProp2);
```